# Assigning text value to variable in cypress to compare changes

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to compare if the value changed correctly after doing certain things in the app.
First I'm trying to assign the value using cypress aliases, but it does not find the value at all. I tried using let and const and same problem exists.

So here is the code which gives error:

```
 cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
        text.replace(/\D/g,'').as("myAlias")
      })
```

I want to reuse this txt variable so that I can compare it later:

```
  cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then((text) => {
            expect(@myAlias).to.be.gte(text.replace(/\D/g,''));
          })
```

So its basically checking if the value changed after doing some set of procedures and is smaller than before. But I cant find correct way to hold this value in a variable

Comment: did u check if text.replace(/\D/g,'') is returning some value? I mean if text is chars then u everything gets replaced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text that you are getting is in string, you have to convert in into a Number (using [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)) if you want to compare the two. And you can use `this` to access myAlias (As, under the hood, aliasing basic objects and primitives utilizes Mocha’s shared context object: that is, aliases are available as this.*)

```
cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', {
    timeout: 15000
}).invoke('text').then((text) => {
    const amountAllBefore = parseInt(text.replace(/\D/g, '')) //this will only work if text.replace(/\D/g, '') returns a number but is string
    cy.wrap(amountAllBefore).as('myAlias')
})

cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', {
    timeout: 15000
}).invoke('text').then((text) => {
    const amountAllAfter = = parseInt(text.replace(/\D/g, '')) //this will only work if text.replace(/\D/g, '') returns a number but is string
    expect(this.myAlias).to.be.greaterThan(amountAllAfter)
})
```

Comment: Im gtting error that `this.myAlias` is undefined

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be `cy.wrap(amountAllBefore)`. Have updated my code.

Comment: No I think it was not the type that caused it. It does not recognize `this` . I used `@myAlias` to get the variable

Comment: Don’t use @ . It is only required when you are accessing the aliases using the `cy.get() ` command. I have used what cypress calls sharing context, you can find more about it here - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context

Comment: I see, but Im getting error: `Cannot read property 'myAlias' of undefined` when using your exact code

Comment: Okay I needed to change arrow function to ES5 and it worked

Answer (score 2):

That might be because you think that Cypress code runs synchronously. But that's not the case. I recommend starting with [this senction](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Assigning-Return-Values) of the documentation and read all other sections this one links, e.g. [this one](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values).

In the second section I linked, there's some code that basically answers your question, even though it deals with a different context.

So, you might want to do something like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then((text1) => {
    const text1 = text1.replace(/\D/g,'');

    // some actions you need to perform

    cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then((text2) => {
        const text2 = text2.replace(/\D/g,'');

        expect(text1).to.eq(text2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I tried using before and worked. It seemed less tidy as it sort of becomes callback hell if using this way. Thats why I was looking for some sort of variable assignment so that I can store values for later comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve an alias inside and `expect()` like that.

Try closure (similar to @pavelsaman's suggestion), but with cy.get('@myAlias') since you want the two blocks separated.

```
cy.get('@myAlias').then(text1 => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=AmountAll]', { timeout: 15000 }).invoke('text').then((text2) => {
    expect(text1).to.be.gte(text2.replace(/\D/g,''));
  })      
})
```